# How to pass an id param via jQuery in a rails 3 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I've read numerous articles and posts on passing an id param via jQuery and have been unable to come up with a variation on my view, js and controller that works. Here's the foundation of code that i have been unable to alter to work. The error i get is "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Answer without an ID)"

view:

```
<%= form_tag update_result_answers_path, :remote => true do %>
   <% @answers.each do |q| %>
      <%= q[0].question %>
      <% [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].each do |f| %>
         <%= radio_button_tag q[1].id, f, f == q[1].score, :class => 'submittable' %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

application.js:

```
$('.submittable').live('change', function() {
$(this).parents('form:first').submit();
return false;
});
```

controller:

```
  def update_result
    @answers = Answer.find params[:id] # THIS LINE PRODUCES THE ERROR BELOW
    @answers.update_attributes params[:score]
  end
```

BTW, At this point I don't care about obtrusive code. I just want something that works. Thanks!

Comment: I think you're going to be a little more clear about what the actual function is of this code. Why are you calling each and then specifying an index `q[0]`? From what I can gather it looks like you are trying to print out a question and then show radio buttons for the different answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the application.js and am closer. This question isn't getting me anywhere. So... i am going to post a different question that approaches the problem from a different angle.

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck? I'm interested in something similar, what is the new link?